# Pandas: How do I add up rows and keep it at the bottom within my statement?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently trying to add totals to the bottom of my columns in preparation for my dataframes to be exported to excel/CSV files. I wanted to know what the best way to do this is.

I had been using
`Wilhelm['Amount'].sum()`, but this is not very efficient as I have to re-add them after I export every time.

Thank you!

Comment: Please share snippet it will be helpful. How many columns are there in DataFrame? Do you want sum of all columns? or you only want to add sum of `Wilhelm['Amount'].sum()`? It's ambiguous question.

Comment: Always provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  when asking for help, so people can understand clearly what you want and reproduce the problem.  Please take the time to read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and revise your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a dataframe of the form:

```
    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun
Budget                      
Milk    10  20  31  52  7   11
Eggs    1   5   1   16  4   58
Bread   22  36  17  8   21  16
Butter  4   5   8   11  36  2
```

And you would like to add a Total row at the bottom which contains the sum of the columns.  This is how I would do this task.

```
# Append a new row containing sum of each column
df.append(pd.Series(df.sum(numeric_only= True),name='Total'))
```

This will produce the dataframe of the following format.

```
    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun
Budget                          
Milk    10  20  31  52  7   11
Eggs    1   5   1   16  4   58
Bread   22  36  17  8   21  16
Butter  4   5   8   11  36  2
Total   37  66  57  87  68  87
```

As was pointed out by @kevin-choon-liang-yew, append is scheduled for depreciation, in which case you would need to use the `concat` function to append a new row as shown below:

```
 pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(df.sum(numeric_only= True)).to_dict(),index=['Total'])])
```

returning the final dataframe.

Comment: I think df.append is starting to get deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.loc['Total'] = df.sum()
```